# Help with static front page blog at /blog

Tags: url-rewriting

I'm interested in installing wordpress and having a static front page and have link to the blog at /blog.

How do I install wordpress in the root directory, but have the blog live at /blog I see how I could do it for the blog urls, but do I just change the wordpress url in general settings for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a codex on this issue here:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page

I haven't been provided all the details of your site from your post. As in what your original site root is from when you installed it.

So i'm making an assumption that this is a new install.

Comment: I started to write an identical question, and half way in, this post appeared in the 'related' section. 7 years later, thanks!!